# Solution Manual for Stochastic Modelling text books

Tags: references, stochastic-processes

I am looking for a graduate level textbook on stochastic modelling for which I can also find a solution manual online. It's like it seems to me that I have understood the concepts but every time I try to solve a new problem I have a hard time figuring it out and piecing together different concepts. So I was planning to look at as many questions and solutions possible, this might help me cement my concepts and also give me an experience with solving problems.

PS- I have a graduate level stochastic modelling class this semester and I really want to ace it.

Comment: This is not what this site is here for.

Comment: Can you direct me to some other site or community where I can ask this question ?

Comment: Have you considered searching this site for relevant questions and answers?  There are more here than you will have time even to read.